# GWT: ClosingEvent setMessage works but message is not showing

Tags: java, gwt

I use Window.ClosingHandler to show confirmation dialog when user press f5 or wants to close tab. Dialog is showing but my message is ignored, browser (Chrome) shows me default message "Changes you made may not be saved." Other browsers also show me default messages instead of mine.

```
Window.ClosingHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent event) {
        event.setMessage("custom message");
    }
});
```

How to show my "custom message"?